# How to rotate an object when being swiped on screen and than decrese its speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have use `3D` level screen when I swipe on screen than my `3D` model rotate left or right and swipe speed increase object rotation speed increase when I swipe ended then automatic decrease rotation speed object speed increase that not descrease and my object rotate continue.
How that maintain with Unity C# code:

```
public class Rotate: MonoBehaviour {

  public Transform fan;

  private bool flagLeft = false;
  private bool flagRight = false;
  private float speedLeft;
  private float speedRight;
  private bool CheckRight = true;
  private bool CheckLeft = true;

  Vector2 firstPressPos;
  Vector2 secondPressPos;
  Vector2 currentSwipe;

  void Start() {
    speedLeft = 1;
    speedRight = 1;

  }

  void Update() {

    Swipe();


    if (flagLeft) {
      fan.transform.Rotate(0, speedLeft * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
    if (flagRight) {
      fan.transform.Rotate(0, -speedRight * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }

  }

  public void Swipe() {
    if (Input.touches.Length > 0) {
      Touch t = Input.GetTouch(0);
      if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        //save began touch 2d point
        firstPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x, t.position.y);
      }
      if (t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
        //save ended touch 2d point
        secondPressPos = new Vector2(t.position.x, t.position.y);

        //create vector from the two points
        currentSwipe = new Vector3(secondPressPos.x - firstPressPos.x, secondPressPos.y - firstPressPos.y);

        //normalize the 2d vector
        currentSwipe.Normalize();

        //swipe upwards
        if (currentSwipe.y > 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5 f) {
          Debug.Log("up swipe");
        }
        //swipe down
        if (currentSwipe.y < 0 && currentSwipe.x > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.x < 0.5 f) {
          Debug.Log("down swipe");
        }
        //swipe left
        if (currentSwipe.x < 0 && currentSwipe.y > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5 f) {
          flagLeft = true;
          if (Debug.isDebugBuild) {
            Debug.Log("Swipe Left");
          }
          if (CheckLeft) {
            speedLeft = speedRight;
            CheckLeft = false;
            CheckRight = true;
          }
          speedLeft += 10;
          Debug.Log("Left Swipe Speed=" + speedLeft);
        }
        //swipe right
        if (currentSwipe.x > 0 && currentSwipe.y > -0.5 f && currentSwipe.y < 0.5 f) {
          flagRight = true;
          Debug.Log("Swipe Right");
          if (CheckRight) {
            speedRight = speedLeft;
            CheckRight = false;
            CheckLeft = true;
          }
          speedRight += 10;
          Debug.Log("Right Swipe Speed=" + speedRight);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to add some code to explain your problem.

Comment: Try solving this with a rigidbody/angular velocity/angular drag. Let Unity do the physics simulation for you, so you just need to add angular force.